# Validating form-field-input inside mat-table (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I have a mat-form-field with a mat-input, which resides inside a material-table. Since the data is inside the material-table-datasource, I can't use a formgroup and validate the input that way. Is there any other method or 'work-around' I could use to approach this?

The field is set up like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="rate">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Currency rate</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell class="description-cell" *matCellDef="let data">
    <mat-form-field class="rate-form-field">
      <input matInput [value]="data.currencyRate" (focusin)="setValue(data.currencyRate)" (focusout)="checkDirty($event, data)"  placeholder="Rate">
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

The value is bound directly from the material-table-datasource. On focusin I save the current value and on focusout I check the saved value against the actual value in the input field. If it is different, I change the value in the datasource. What I want to achieve is that I try to save when it is empty and/or with invalid number/letters, it should throw an error underneath the form-field.

Comment: have you tried with `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: No, as I remembered reading that it would be deprecated in Angular 7. But, when googling now it looks like this is just for reactive forms. Does this mean that using  ngModel is the 'correct' way to do it in this case? Will give it a try - thanks for the info!